# Proof modular equality by induction

Tags: induction, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to prove using induction that $5^{2^{x-2}} \equiv 1 + 2^x \pmod{2^{x+1}}$

So far, I have:

1. Base case: $x = 2, 5 \equiv 5 \pmod{8}$, It is true. $x = 3, 25 \equiv 9 \pmod{16}$, It is true.
2. Inductive step: let $x = n$ Assume $5^{2^{n-2}} \equiv 1 + 2^n \pmod{2^{n+1}}$ is true, so I need proof, that $5^{2^{n-1}} \equiv 1 + 2^{n+1} \pmod{2^{n+2}}$.

I tried express new equation through the old. But I am getting errors.

Comment: Please, correct your latex. Respect others.

Comment: I proposed an edit. Please check if i did it right @max

Comment: @Swapnil Tripathi, Thank you for editing. That's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \begin{align*}\begin{split}
5^{2^{n-1}} &= (5^{2^{n-2}})^2 \\
            &= (1 + 2^{n}+2^{n+1}a)^2 \\
            &= 1+ (2^n)^2+(2^{n+1}a)^2+
               2\cdot2^n+2\cdot2^{n+2}a+2\cdot2^{n}\cdot2^{n+1}a\\
            &=1+2^{n+1}+2^{n+2}b
\end{split}\end{align*}$$